# Using free() on non-heap objects in C

Tags: c

I couldn't find what the behaviour of this action actually is. 
It doesn't seem to cause any run-time errors so I guess it just does nothing? 
I found about this technique only recently while I was writing my coursework. 
Actually, my professor seems to be an advocate of this but I fail to grasp how it works without breaking. 
Basically, the idea is to use a variable as a test object or guard for a struct pointer, and then pass this "dummy" variable to a function. 
I'll try giving an example with code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Struct {
    int a;
    struct Struct *next;
    float c;
};

int
stuff(struct Struct *ptr) {
    free(ptr);
    return 1; // always assume true for the sake of example
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Struct *ptr;
    struct Struct test;
    int retval;

    if ((ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Struct *))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // some magic goes here...
    test = *ptr;
    retval = stuff(&test);
    if (retval) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In my coursework I had to free a struct's two struct pointer members one after another, and then free the struct's memory. Since either of the struct pointer members could be operating on data, if one could not be freed then the whole main struct should not be freed and changes should be reverted. 
This approach of a variable on the stack to work out whether memory can be safely freed without compromising running data is what's baffling me. I'm not really sure what I'm even not understanding. 
Would anyone aware of this methodology enlighten me on the details?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct Struct))`

Comment: this pattern seems do common it's depressing; you have a struct and you want to free it, often traversing it, but some of the structs on the path may be put on the stack and not need deallocation(and is faster). now you can no longer tell if you should or not free something reliably because there's a flag that may or may not be valid, and now you're in hell... the depressing part is the conditional makes it better performance but makes it no longer uniform to reason about. I guess managed memory should be separate from unmanaged memory to keep system maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

> couldn't find what the behaviour of [using free() on non-heap objects in C] action actually is.

It's undefined behavior.  That's it, you can't make any assumptions about what will occur.  `test` is a copy of the memory at `*ptr`.  Calling `free` on a pointer which was not returned by `malloc` (and friends) results in undefined behavior.

Either you misunderstood your professor, or your professor doesn't know what s/he is talking about. All you need do is to read the documentation:

> The behavior is undefined if ptr does not match a pointer returned earlier by malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). Also, the behavior is undefined if the memory area referred to by ptr has already been deallocated, that is, free() or realloc() has already been called with ptr as the argument and no calls to malloc(), calloc() or realloc() resulted in a pointer equal to ptr afterwards.

---

> It doesn't seem to cause any run-time errors so I guess it just does nothing?

Welcome to C :).  You're used to languages which smack your hand right away when you do something terribly wrong.  C doesn't really care what you do. C gives you freedom, but that freedom works both ways (i.e., you're free to shoot your foot off as well).

Comment: I just reviewed my code and it seems I have greatly misunderstood this mechanism. The "test" variable in my example should serve as a copy of the struct that I'm about to free. So when I try freeing consecutive struct members and one of them fails, then I can use the copy (or copies) to revert back the previously freed pointers. My bad..

Comment: @jrhetf4xb: Ok, though I don't see why freeing a member of a struct would ever "fail".  Also, you cannot revert back to the previously freed pointers.  Those are now garbage and dereferencing them will result once again in undefined behavior.

Comment: Indeed, `free` cannot fail per the standard - it can only succeed or crash.  It might be worth mentioning, though, that `free(NULL)` does *not* crash; it just silently does nothing.

Comment: Basically, we're emulating a thread package, or how the operating system would schedule different threads. I have to build a message passing facility based on semaphores and the like. So my implementation of a channel requires two semaphore structs.

Comment: If I destroy a channel I have to free the memory held by the two semaphore structs. If either of them is operating (they have threads on their queues) then I cannot free their memory. Thus the use of a temporary variable to revert back the changes if semaphore 1 is freed but after it semaphore 2 cannot be freed. However, it's a good point that freed memory cannot be referenced back. Now I am really confused since neither approaches are feasible but my (first) approach was marked as correct...

Comment: Oh, and I can't free the memory held by the channel before freeing the memory held by the two semaphores... My first solution was to create a new semaphore in place of the deleted one, if the second couldn't be freed, but this seems inefficient. My second one was to just peek directly if the queues of the semaphores were empty, but then the person that had to mark me noted that it was bad to access other "packages"'s members/functions. So my final approach seemed to be the commonly accepted answer and it seemed a bit weird to me...

Comment: @Zack: Correction: `free()` can only succeed or exhibit undefined behavior. And yes, `free(NULL)` is required by the C standard to do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I ran this test and got a core dump. Ubuntu Linux with gcc 4.6.3. I tried several other variations on the theme and core dumped all of them.

Here is the description of free from the Linux man page:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before,
>   undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

That word *undefined* is key. That means that it will not necessarily crash. Those are the worst kind of errors to debug - you are much better having a bug that crashes reliably every time. This may be safe for some configurations of compiler and libraries, but it is not for all of them. The method is best avoided.